# Java: Method to instantiate a particular sub class of an abstract class

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class, subclass

How to create an object of a particular sub-class of an abstract class based on the classNameString generated on runtime? Let say there is an abstract class A

```
public abstract class A {
    abstract protected void method();               
    A getNewInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        return this.getClass().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Let there be N sub-classes viz A1, A2,.., AN. There is a need to write following method which would return a subclass object based on classNameString

```
A getSubClassObject(String classNameString)
```

I have following two *ugly* implementations
First:

```
A getSubClassObject(String classNameString){
    A obj = null;
    if(classNameString.equals("A1")){
        obj = new A1();
    }else if(classNameString.equals("A2")){
        obj = new A2();         
    }
    ...
    }else if(classNameString.equals("AN")){
        obj = new AN();         
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Second:

```
A getSubClassObject(String classNameString){
    A obj = null;
    try {
       obj = this.subClassObjectsHashMap().get(classNameString).getNewInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
private HashMap<String, A> subClassObjectsHashMap(){
    HashMap<String, A> subClassObjectsHashMap = new HashMap<String,A>();
    subClassObjectsHashMap.put("A1", new A1());
    subClassObjectsHashMap.put("A2", new A2());
    ....
    subClassObjectsHashMap.put("AN", new AN());
    return subClassObjectsHashMap;
}
```

Are there any better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: COnstruct the class name and load that class by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if all the constructors receive the same parameter (in your example, no paramaters) you can do

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("fully.qualified.class.nane");
A a = (A) clazz.newInstace();
```

Both methods can throw various exceptions, so you need to add some catch blocks.

Comment: What if there had been same parameters for all the sub-classes? For e.g Base class constructor is
`A(String str){}`
and sub-classes constructors are like
`A1(String str, String str2){super(str);}`

Comment: Then you need to call something like `Constructor c = Clazz.getConstructor( new Object[] {String.class} );` which returns the constructor that takes a String as a parameter. And then `A a = c.newInstance( new Object["your_string"] )`. Read a bit about Java Reflection, it's the feature in java which allows to open a class in runtime and do some interesting stuff (like calling private methods :p).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Java Reflection is indeed cool, just what I wanted :)

Answer (score 4):

what about doing something like

```
return (A)Class.forName(runtimeClassName).newInstance();
```

with appropriate error handling?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Java API at java.lang.Class, methods forName(String) and newInstance()